# Run-time and Compile-time Versions of Integer Power

Tags: c++, template-meta-programming

I have implemented exponentiation with integer base and non-negative integer exponent for practicing purposes.

Of course there is some upper limit what numbers can be exponentiated within the int datatype, but I wasn't concerned about this at this point. But any suggestions how to handle it are welcome.

There are four variantions of the power function:

```
// full runtime version
int ipow(int, unsigned int);

// full compile time version
template<int, unsigned int> int ipow();

// only base is known at compile time
template<int> int ipow_base(unsigned int);

// only exponent is known at compile time
template<unsigned int> int ipow_exp(int);
```

I am interested in a general review, if I'm doing something wrong, could I have made something more explicit, etc...

My only restriction is that I am not (yet) intersted in post C++17 features.

```
#include <cstddef>
#include <stdexcept>

template<const unsigned int exponent>
constexpr int ipow_exp(int base)
{
    if (exponent == 0) return 1;
    return base * ipow_exp<exponent-1>(base);
}

template<>
constexpr int ipow_exp<1>(int base)
{
    return base;
}

template<>
constexpr int ipow_exp<0>(int base)
{
    if (base == 0) throw std::logic_error("0^0 is undefined.");
    return 1;
}

template<const int base>
constexpr int ipow_base(unsigned int exponent)
{
    if (exponent == 0) return 1;
    return base * ipow_base<base>(exponent-1);
}

template<>
constexpr int ipow_base<2>(unsigned int exponent)
{
    return 1 << exponent;
}

template<>
constexpr int ipow_base<1>(unsigned int exponent)
{
    return 1;
}

template<>
constexpr int ipow_base<0>(unsigned int exponent)
{
    if (exponent == 0) throw std::logic_error("0^0 is undefined.");
    return 0;
}

template<const int base, const unsigned int exponent>
constexpr int ipow()
{
    static_assert(exponent != 0 || base != 0, "0^0 is undefined.");
    if (exponent == 1 || base == 0 || base == 1) {
        return base;
    }
    return ipow_base<base>(exponent);
}

int ipow(int base, unsigned int exponent)
{
    if (exponent == 0) {
        if (base == 0) throw std::logic_error("0^0 is undefined.");
        return 1;
    }
    int result = base;
    while (--exponent > 0) {
        result *= base;
    }
    return result;
}



#include <cassert>

int main()
{
    int tmp;
    bool thrown = false;

    // full runtime version
    assert(ipow(0,1) == 0);
    assert(ipow(0,2) == 0);
    assert(ipow(0,3) == 0);
    assert(ipow(0,50) == 0);
    assert(ipow(1,0) == 1);
    assert(ipow(1,1) == 1);
    assert(ipow(1,2) == 1);
    assert(ipow(1,50) == 1);
    assert(ipow(2,0) == 1);
    assert(ipow(2,1) == 2);
    assert(ipow(2,2) == 4);
    assert(ipow(2,3) == 8);
    assert(ipow(2,10) == 1024);
    assert(ipow(3,0) == 1);
    assert(ipow(3,1) == 3);
    assert(ipow(3,2) == 9);
    assert(ipow(3,3) == 27);
    assert(ipow(3,4) == 81);
    assert(ipow(5,0) == 1);
    assert(ipow(5,1) == 5);
    assert(ipow(5,2) == 25);
    assert(ipow(5,3) == 125);
    assert(ipow(5,4) == 625);
    assert(ipow(-1,0) == 1);
    assert(ipow(-1,1) == -1);
    assert(ipow(-1,2) == 1);
    assert(ipow(-1,3) == -1);
    assert(ipow(-1,4) == 1);
    assert(ipow(-1,31) == -1);
    assert(ipow(-1,32) == 1);
    assert(ipow(-2,0) == 1);
    assert(ipow(-2,1) == -2);
    assert(ipow(-2,2) == 4);
    assert(ipow(-2,9) == -512);
    assert(ipow(-2,10) == 1024);
    assert(ipow(-5,0) == 1);
    assert(ipow(-5,1) == -5);
    assert(ipow(-5,2) == 25);
    assert(ipow(-5,3) == -125);
    assert(ipow(-5,4) == 625);

    thrown = false;
    try {
        ipow(0,0);
    } catch (std::logic_error e){
        thrown = true;
    }
    assert(thrown);

    // compile time exponent version
    tmp = ipow_exp<1>(0); assert(tmp == 0);
    tmp = ipow_exp<2>(0); assert(tmp == 0);
    tmp = ipow_exp<3>(0); assert(tmp == 0);
    tmp = ipow_exp<50>(0); assert(tmp == 0);
    tmp = ipow_exp<0>(1); assert(tmp == 1);
    tmp = ipow_exp<1>(1); assert(tmp == 1);
    tmp = ipow_exp<2>(1); assert(tmp == 1);
    tmp = ipow_exp<50>(1); assert(tmp == 1);
    tmp = ipow_exp<0>(2); assert(tmp == 1);
    tmp = ipow_exp<1>(2); assert(tmp == 2);
    tmp = ipow_exp<2>(2); assert(tmp == 4);
    tmp = ipow_exp<3>(2); assert(tmp == 8);
    tmp = ipow_exp<10>(2); assert(tmp == 1024);
    tmp = ipow_exp<0>(3); assert(tmp == 1);
    tmp = ipow_exp<1>(3); assert(tmp == 3);
    tmp = ipow_exp<2>(3); assert(tmp == 9);
    tmp = ipow_exp<3>(3); assert(tmp == 27);
    tmp = ipow_exp<4>(3); assert(tmp == 81);
    tmp = ipow_exp<0>(5); assert(tmp == 1);
    tmp = ipow_exp<1>(5); assert(tmp == 5);
    tmp = ipow_exp<2>(5); assert(tmp == 25);
    tmp = ipow_exp<3>(5); assert(tmp == 125);
    tmp = ipow_exp<4>(5); assert(tmp == 625);
    tmp = ipow_exp<0>(-1); assert(tmp == 1);
    tmp = ipow_exp<1>(-1); assert(tmp == -1);
    tmp = ipow_exp<2>(-1); assert(tmp == 1);
    tmp = ipow_exp<3>(-1); assert(tmp == -1);
    tmp = ipow_exp<4>(-1); assert(tmp == 1);
    tmp = ipow_exp<31>(-1); assert(tmp == -1);
    tmp = ipow_exp<32>(-1); assert(tmp == 1);
    tmp = ipow_exp<0>(-2); assert(tmp == 1);
    tmp = ipow_exp<1>(-2); assert(tmp == -2);
    tmp = ipow_exp<2>(-2); assert(tmp == 4);
    tmp = ipow_exp<9>(-2); assert(tmp == -512);
    tmp = ipow_exp<10>(-2); assert(tmp == 1024);
    tmp = ipow_exp<0>(-5); assert(tmp == 1);
    tmp = ipow_exp<1>(-5); assert(tmp == -5);
    tmp = ipow_exp<2>(-5); assert(tmp == 25);
    tmp = ipow_exp<3>(-5); assert(tmp == -125);
    tmp = ipow_exp<4>(-5); assert(tmp == 625);

    thrown = false;
    try {
        ipow_exp<0>(0);
    } catch (std::logic_error e){
        thrown = true;
    }
    assert(thrown);

    // compile time base version
    tmp = ipow_base<0>(1); assert(tmp == 0);
    tmp = ipow_base<0>(2); assert(tmp == 0);
    tmp = ipow_base<0>(3); assert(tmp == 0);
    tmp = ipow_base<0>(50); assert(tmp == 0);
    tmp = ipow_base<1>(0); assert(tmp == 1);
    tmp = ipow_base<1>(1); assert(tmp == 1);
    tmp = ipow_base<1>(2); assert(tmp == 1);
    tmp = ipow_base<1>(50); assert(tmp == 1);
    tmp = ipow_base<2>(0); assert(tmp == 1);
    tmp = ipow_base<2>(1); assert(tmp == 2);
    tmp = ipow_base<2>(2); assert(tmp == 4);
    tmp = ipow_base<2>(3); assert(tmp == 8);
    tmp = ipow_base<2>(10); assert(tmp == 1024);
    tmp = ipow_base<3>(0); assert(tmp == 1);
    tmp = ipow_base<3>(1); assert(tmp == 3);
    tmp = ipow_base<3>(2); assert(tmp == 9);
    tmp = ipow_base<3>(3); assert(tmp == 27);
    tmp = ipow_base<3>(4); assert(tmp == 81);
    tmp = ipow_base<5>(0); assert(tmp == 1);
    tmp = ipow_base<5>(1); assert(tmp == 5);
    tmp = ipow_base<5>(2); assert(tmp == 25);
    tmp = ipow_base<5>(3); assert(tmp == 125);
    tmp = ipow_base<5>(4); assert(tmp == 625);
    tmp = ipow_base<-1>(0); assert(tmp == 1);
    tmp = ipow_base<-1>(1); assert(tmp == -1);
    tmp = ipow_base<-1>(2); assert(tmp == 1);
    tmp = ipow_base<-1>(3); assert(tmp == -1);
    tmp = ipow_base<-1>(4); assert(tmp == 1);
    tmp = ipow_base<-1>(31); assert(tmp == -1);
    tmp = ipow_base<-1>(32); assert(tmp == 1);
    tmp = ipow_base<-2>(0); assert(tmp == 1);
    tmp = ipow_base<-2>(1); assert(tmp == -2);
    tmp = ipow_base<-2>(2); assert(tmp == 4);
    tmp = ipow_base<-2>(9); assert(tmp == -512);
    tmp = ipow_base<-2>(10); assert(tmp == 1024);
    tmp = ipow_base<-5>(0); assert(tmp == 1);
    tmp = ipow_base<-5>(1); assert(tmp == -5);
    tmp = ipow_base<-5>(2); assert(tmp == 25);
    tmp = ipow_base<-5>(3); assert(tmp == -125);
    tmp = ipow_base<-5>(4); assert(tmp == 625);

    thrown = false;
    try {
        ipow_base<0>(0);
    } catch (std::logic_error e){
        thrown = true;
    }
    assert(thrown);

    // full compile time version
    tmp = ipow<0,1>(); assert(tmp == 0);
    tmp = ipow<0,2>(); assert(tmp == 0);
    tmp = ipow<0,3>(); assert(tmp == 0);
    tmp = ipow<0,50>(); assert(tmp == 0);
    tmp = ipow<1,0>(); assert(tmp == 1);
    tmp = ipow<1,1>(); assert(tmp == 1);
    tmp = ipow<1,2>(); assert(tmp == 1);
    tmp = ipow<1,50>(); assert(tmp == 1);
    tmp = ipow<2,0>(); assert(tmp == 1);
    tmp = ipow<2,1>(); assert(tmp == 2);
    tmp = ipow<2,2>(); assert(tmp == 4);
    tmp = ipow<2,3>(); assert(tmp == 8);
    tmp = ipow<2,10>(); assert(tmp == 1024);
    tmp = ipow<3,0>(); assert(tmp == 1);
    tmp = ipow<3,1>(); assert(tmp == 3);
    tmp = ipow<3,2>(); assert(tmp == 9);
    tmp = ipow<3,3>(); assert(tmp == 27);
    tmp = ipow<3,4>(); assert(tmp == 81);
    tmp = ipow<5,0>(); assert(tmp == 1);
    tmp = ipow<5,1>(); assert(tmp == 5);
    tmp = ipow<5,2>(); assert(tmp == 25);
    tmp = ipow<5,3>(); assert(tmp == 125);
    tmp = ipow<5,4>(); assert(tmp == 625);
    tmp = ipow<-1,0>(); assert(tmp == 1);
    tmp = ipow<-1,1>(); assert(tmp == -1);
    tmp = ipow<-1,2>(); assert(tmp == 1);
    tmp = ipow<-1,3>(); assert(tmp == -1);
    tmp = ipow<-1,4>(); assert(tmp == 1);
    tmp = ipow<-1,31>(); assert(tmp == -1);
    tmp = ipow<-1,32>(); assert(tmp == 1);
    tmp = ipow<-2,0>(); assert(tmp == 1);
    tmp = ipow<-2,1>(); assert(tmp == -2);
    tmp = ipow<-2,2>(); assert(tmp == 4);
    tmp = ipow<-2,9>(); assert(tmp == -512);
    tmp = ipow<-2,10>(); assert(tmp == 1024);
    tmp = ipow<-5,0>(); assert(tmp == 1);
    tmp = ipow<-5,1>(); assert(tmp == -5);
    tmp = ipow<-5,2>(); assert(tmp == 25);
    tmp = ipow<-5,3>(); assert(tmp == -125);
    tmp = ipow<-5,4>(); assert(tmp == 625);

#ifdef TEST_COMPILE_ERRORS
    ipow<0,0>();
#endif

    return 0;
}
```

```
$ g++ --version
g++ (Ubuntu 7.4.0-1ubuntu1~18.04.1) 7.4.0
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Avoid large recursion

The unspecialized `ipow_base()` may recurse `exponent` times before multiplying.  Just defer to the general case here:

```
template<const int base>
constexpr int ipow_base(unsigned int exponent)
{
    return ipow(base, exponent);
}
```

## Use binary exponentiation for efficiency with larger exponents

These functions (other than the specializations) scale linearly with the exponent value, but could scale logarithmically like this:

```
template<const unsigned int exponent>
constexpr int ipow_exp(int base)
{
    return (exponent & 1 ? base : 1) * ipow_exp<exponent/2>(base*base);
}

constexpr int ipow(int base, unsigned int exponent)
{
    if (!exponent && !base) {
        throw std::logic_error("0^0 is undefined.");
    }

    if (base == 2) {
        return 1 << exponent;
    }

    int result = 1;
    int term = base;
    while (exponent) {
        if (exponent & 1) {
            result *= term;
        }
        term *= term;
        exponent /= 2;
    }
    return result;
}
```

## Extend to other integer types

Users would probably like to be able to use any `std::is_integral` type for `base` (e.g. `unsigned long`), so that ought to be a template type.

## Simplify tests for throwing

We don't need the `thrown` variable here:

> ```
> thrown = false;
> try {
>     ipow(0,0);
> } catch (std::logic_error e){
>     thrown = true;
> }
> assert(thrown);
> ```

Just assert in the `try` block:

```
try {
    ipow(0,0);
    assert(false);
} catch (std::logic_error& e) {
    // expected
}
```

Better still, use one of the many available test frameworks rather than simple `assert()`.  That would help in several ways, such as detecting multiple failures per run, and showing actual and expected values for comparison.

Answer (score 4):

## You might be able to use `std::pow()` in `constexpr` expressions in C++11

Since this post was not tagged "reinventing-the-wheel", I want to point out that some compilers (notably GCC) will compile the below C++11 code:

```
#include <cmath>

constexpr int ipow(int a, int b) {
    return std::pow(a, b);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    static_assert(ipow(-5, 3) == -125);
    return ipow(argc, 2);
}
```

One drawback is that `std::pow()` converts integer arguments to `double`, which at run-time may or may not result in slower computation than using `int`. Also, while for `int` there is no loss of precision, if you would want to use `int64_t`, there is a potential loss of precision.

The other drawback, as pointed out by Oliver Schonrock, is that not all compilers allow `constexpr` use of `std::pow()`. As explained in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50477974/constexpr-exp-log-pow),
`constexpr` math functions were only allowed in C++11 but not in C++14. But there are libraries that provide `constexpr` math functions, see for example [Sprout's `pow()` implementation](https://github.com/bolero-MURAKAMI/Sprout/blob/master/sprout/math/pow.hpp).

## Zero to the power zero is one*

With most programming languages, one usually finds that [`pow(0, 0) == 1`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero_to_the_power_of_zero#IEEE_floating-point_standard). You should ensure your solution also returns one in that case, to ensure consistency, regardless of your personal feelings about zero to the power zero.

As a bonus, by having a well-defined result for `ipow(0, 0)`, it no longer throws exceptions, and you can get rid of some of the specializations.

## Catch exceptions by const reference

Make it a habit to catch exceptions by const reference. Apart from being a little bit faster (although this of course is the least of your worries when exceptions are being thrown), it ensures you don't lose information when the exception thrown is of a derived class. See [this StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2522299/c-catch-blocks-catch-exception-by-value-or-reference) for more information.

Comment: "following code is valid C++11". Are you sure? It compiles for me under gcc-9.2. but clang-9 throws "static_assert expression is not an integral constant expression".  This doesn't mention `constexpr`: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/pow . This caught my eye because I recently personally implemented a limited compile time `pow` exactly because it only works in gcc as a non-standard extension?

Comment: Summary of all 3 main compilers. Latest stable of each. https://godbolt.org/z/07b7Ww  Only gcc seems to support it. Also tried trunk clang, which doesn't work either.

Comment: Woops, it's indeed not guaranteed to be `constexpr`. Apparently it was only *allowed* to be `constexpr` in C++11. Thanks for the godbolt link!

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Although I must say 0^0=1 gives me headache :)

Comment: Heya, sorry I removed the accepted answer. You made some valid points. But I find the other answer a bit more useful so I decided to accept that one instead...

Comment: That's perfectly fine, you should indeed accept the answer that is most useful to you!